# Proportional scaling and centering of all web content up to a maximum size

Tags: javascript, html, css, scale, translate

I have need of an application that scales proportionally (like TV rather than web) and keeps the content centred when the window is resized.

I would like to layout my application inside a widescreen box 16:9 (1200px x 675px). When the window is larger than this then the content scales up proportionally, when smaller the content shrinks. I would like the scaling to apply to images, text, svg and HTML5 video containers. I can restrict the solution to modern browsers only.

I have had a play with CSS translate and transform but the scaling is acting rather strange. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1peyjq65/1/).

HTML

```
<div id='container'>
            <h1>H1</h1>
            <h2>H2</h2>
            <p>P</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #container {
        background-color: #7F3;
        font-size: 60px;
        position: absolute;
        width : 1200px;
        height : 675px;
        top: 50%;
        left : 50%;
        /*transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
        transform-origin: center center;
    }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var W = $(window).width()
    var MAX_SIZE = 1600
    var val = Math.min(W,MAX_SIZE) * / 1200 

    $('#container').css({
        'left' : '50%',
        'right' : '50%',
        'transform': 'scale(' + val + ')' + ' translate(-50%,-50%)',
    })

})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get proper scaling you would need to use SVG for pretty much everything. Size everthing in proportional values such as % or viewport units and so on. It's not a simple fix. You need to start from core principals and **never** use a non-proportianl `length`.

Comment: The following page links to a design that successfully uses `scale` in a somewhat limited context: https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/. Is scale likely to cause me problems then if I go down this route?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Scaling is fine in certain circumstances but lack of quality is always likely to be a factor.